# Fetch incremental records using sql query

Tags: sql-server-2005

> Have User search screen where by default i get 1000 top records order
>   by User Id(sql query) and display in front end as page per records
>   (using paging in front end) . Now suppose i have 20 paging number
>   where it has been set 50 records to display per page. Now when user
>   clicks on 20 th paging number i want to fetch more 1000 records from
>   database but that should be incremental based

**For eg :**

In user table have got 6000 users

> 1) Fethced 1000 users from user table order by User Id for first
>       time
>
> 2) Now user clicks the 20th paging number , and again i need to make a
>   DB call to fetch 1000 users order by user id but here  fetching of
>   1000 users should be done from 5000 users and any of the user fetched again shouldn't be from the step (1)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function

```
WITH T as 
(
SELECT tUsers.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) as RowNum
       FROM tUsers
)

SELECT * FROM T 
       WHERE RowNum between 50*20 AND 50*20+50
       ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: And excellent example of paging using `ROW_NUMBER()` is available here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12338/Using-ROW_NUMBER-to-paginate-your-data-with-SQL-Se

Comment: @dotNET It's fine but there is an error in SP_GETZIPCODES from this link. You should add an `order by` class to the end of the query to get right results `...WHERE num > @start ORDER BY num;`. Otherwise you can get mess of records from the next pages.